# pick only year and month from date picker in bootstrap 3

Tags: datepicker, codeigniter-3

I want an input only for year and month not the day, therefore, I used the existing code on stack overflow but that seems out dated i-e use the prvious versons of bootstrap and jQuery but not working on my side as i use bootstrap 3 and jQuery 3.1. Kindly share the updated code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Too late for an answer, but maybe it will help someone else

For actual version;

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker10'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'MM/YYYY'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Old version

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetimepicker4">Min View Mode</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4" data-plugin="datetimepicker" data-options="{ viewMode: 'years', format: 'MM/YYYY' }">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon bg-info text-white">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```